# How to show AVplayer current play duration in UISlider

Tags: ios, uislider, avplayer

I am using a custom UISlider to implement the scrubbing while playing a video in AVPlayer. Trying to figure out the best way to show the current play time and the remaining duration on the respective ends of the UISlider as it usually is shown in MPMoviePlayerController.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put a UILabel at each end.  Update them using `-[AVPlayer addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:queue:usingBlock:]`.  Compute the time remaining using `-[AVPlayer currentTime]` and `-[AVPlayerItem duration]`.

Comment: I am using a UIToolBar to place the UISlider, on putting the UILabel it acts like a separate UIBarButtonItem along with the glowing effect. So it doesn't gel well like in MPMoviePlayerController.

Comment: Instead of putting the UISlider directly in the UIToolBar, put a UIView in the toolbar.  Make the UISlider a subview of the UIView, along with two UILabels.

Answer (score 12):

**Swift 4.x**

```
let player = AVPlayer()
player.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: CMTime.init(value: 1, timescale: 1), queue: .main, using: { time in
        if let duration = player.currentItem?.duration {
          let duration = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration), time = CMTimeGetSeconds(time)
          let progress = (time/duration)
          if progress > targetProgress {
              print(progress)
             //Update slider value
          }
        }
    })
```

*or*

```
extension AVPlayer {
    func addProgressObserver(action:@escaping ((Double) -> Void)) -> Any {
        return self.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: CMTime.init(value: 1, timescale: 1), queue: .main, using: { time in
            if let duration = self.currentItem?.duration {
                let duration = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration), time = CMTimeGetSeconds(time)
                let progress = (time/duration)
                action(progress)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

*Use*

```
let player = AVPlayer()
player.addProgressObserver { progress in
   //Update slider value
}
```

Comment: I used the extension method and worked perfectly. Thank you very much. Is there an easy way to let users select the current time with slider?

Answer (score 0):

```
[slider setMaximumValue:[AVPlayerItem duration]];
//use NSTimer, run repeat function
-(void)updateValueSlide{
      [slider setValue:[AVPlayerItem duration]];
 }
```